# Simplifiation of a double sum involving powers of 2 same numbers

Tags: real-analysis, summation

How can I simplify this double sum:

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac{4^{2kl}×5^{k^{2}}-4^{k^{2}}×5^{2kl}}{4^{l^{2}}×5^{l^{2}}×4^{k^{2}}×5^{k^{2}}}$$

Comment: Please advise if the edit is not correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Autolatry: It is OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*:
You can write 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{l=1}^k \frac{4^{2kl}×5^{k^{2}}-4^{k^{2}}×5^{2kl}}{4^{l^{2}}×5^{l^{2}}×4^{k^{2}}×5^{k^{2}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \sum_{l=1}^k 4^{-(k-l)^2} \cdot 5^{-l^2} - 5^{-(k-l)^2} \cdot 5^{-l^2} $$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}( \sum_{l=1}^k 4^{-(k-l)^2} \cdot 5^{-l^2} -
\sum_{l=1}^k 5^{-(k-l)^2} \cdot 4^{-l^2} )
$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}( \sum_{l=1}^k 4^{-(k-l)^2} \cdot 5^{-l^2} -
\sum_{l=0}^{k-1} 5^{-l^2} \cdot 4^{-(k-l)^2} )
$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (5^{-k^2} - 4^{-k^2})
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{l=1}^k\frac1{5^{l^2}4^{(k-l)^2}}-\frac1{4^{k^2}5^{(k-l)^2}}\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{4^05^{k^2}}-\frac1{5^04^{k^2}}$$
but I don't know how to simplify what remains.